# Find the cross product of the sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{1, \{1, \{ 1\} \} \}$
>
> Find $A \times A$.

So, $A$ has 2 elements, thus It will be $(1, \{ 1, \{1 \} \})$ and $(\{ 1, \{1 \} \}, 1)$ and $(\{ 1, \{1 \} \}, \{ 1, \{1 \} \})$  and $(1, 1)$?

Comment: Correct.  Those are the four elements of $A\times A$.  All that remains is to write $A\times A$ as a set with proper notation.

Comment: Those are the elements (which you correctly identified). The cross product is the set of them.

Comment: The operation $\times$ between sets is usually called the "cartesian product". The name "cross product" is usually reserved for one of the products of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. Note that if $A$ has $n$ elements, $A\times A$ will have $n^2$ elements.